# fastest way of downloading multiple images in android

Tags: android

I am facing an issue with downloading images from server. I tried webservice and direct url downloading of images. I found direct downloading is much slower when we have large number of images to be downloaded. Can anyone refer me,which is the fastest way of downloading images for an android application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tutorial and sample application (BitmapFun) by Google:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

You can get a lot of insights on how to load multiple images asynchronously and fast.

Answer (score 0):

I use this https://code.google.com/p/android-query/ but I'm curious to know if there is something better!